# Check for DNS leaks on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, dns, vpn, openvpn

I currently run Ubuntu server 18.04.1 LTS.
I hav setup split tunnel VPN and it seems to work fine, however I want to check for DNS leaks. Is there a way to do this with the command-line? Can't really open a browser in Ubuntu server...

Updated with info for heynnema:

```
ls -al /etc/openvpn

total 52
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root  4096 Nov  2 21:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 99 root root  4096 Nov  3 12:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1403 Nov  2 20:35 ca.crt
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 Sep  5 14:43 client
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1597 Nov  2 20:39 iptables.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    18 Nov  2 20:36 login.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   670 Nov  2 21:29 openvpn.conf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   623 Nov  2 20:40 routing.sh
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 Sep  5 14:43 server
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   636 Nov  2 20:35 tls.key
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 11773 Nov 12  2017 update-systemd-resolved
```

#

```
grep -i hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

#
The section "prevent DNS leakage" I got from guide online, however the VPN do not work at all for me if I enable that command.

```
up/down/down-pre
#up and down scripts to be executed when VPN starts or stops
up /etc/openvpn/iptables.sh
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre

# prevent DNS leakage
#dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

More info:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Niftiest Software – www.niftiestsoftware.com
# Modified version by HTPC Guides – www.htpcguides.com

export INTERFACE="tun0"
export VPNUSER="vpn"
export LOCALIP="192.168.1.10"
export NETIF="enp1s0"

# flushes all the iptables rules, if you have other rules to use then add them into the script
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -F -t filter

# mark packets from $VPNUSER
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --dest $LOCALIP -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LOCALIP -p udp --dport 53 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LOCALIP -p tcp --dport 53 -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --src $LOCALIP -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --save-mark

# allow responses
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# block everything incoming on $INTERFACE to prevent accidental exposing of ports
iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -j REJECT

# let $VPNUSER access lo and $INTERFACE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $INTERFACE -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT

# all packets on $INTERFACE needs to be masqueraded
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTERFACE -j MASQUERADE

# reject connections from predator IP going over $NETIF
iptables -A OUTPUT ! --src $LOCALIP -o $NETIF -j REJECT

# Start routing script
/etc/openvpn/routing.sh

exit 0
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what you mean by "DNS leaks".

Comment: @mdpc a DNS leak is when you access sites using the VPN tunnel, and it needs to perform a DNS lookup, and it uses DNS servers outside of the VPN provider/secure tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:

```
ssh -X VPNuser@server
firefox
```

Then surf to a website for dns-leak test.

Comment: did you try this script https://github.com/macvk/dnsleaktest ? it seems to me this is exactly what you need.

Comment: @vadim_hr No, but my solution worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` for nameserver addresses. If it says 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.53, then you probably have DNS leaks. You should see the IP address of your VPN DNS, and 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.53 (which probably point to your router at 192.168.0.1/192.168.1.1).</strike>

The router is probably set to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 or 208.67.222.222/208.67.220.220 for its DNS routers, and you'll have a DNS leak.

If you can SSH into your server and get a GUI you can check http://dnsleak.com or http://dnsleaktest.com to check for DNS leaks.

Note: this may not apply to a "split tunnel VPN setup", I don't know.

**Update #1:**

The user is running with `openvpn-system-resolved`, so most of my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: The problem with this is that I use openvpn-system-resolved. Which means I don't use /etc/resolv.conf. So running cat /etc/resolv.conf will always give me 127.0.0.53. However when I run systemd-resolve --status the correct DNS is showed for my tunnel.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `ls -al /etc/openvpn` and `grep -i hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` and the `up/down/down-pre` lines from your .ovpn script. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: The post is now updated with the requested info.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg  I see that your UP command `up /etc/openvpn/iptables.sh` uses a .sh file that I don't recognize from the distribution. What is it, and what are the contents? I installed openvpn-systemd-resolved, and made the file mods, and I think it's working, but `systemd-resolve --status` doesn't show the updated DNS addresses.

Comment: Updated again. Also the guide I followed was this: https://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-debian-8-ubuntu-16-04/
However, that's for and older distribution and do not work for 18.04.01. However there are more info on how to get it working on 18, which I also followed here:
https://forum.htpcguides.com/Thread-Split-Tunnel-Guide-for-Ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Now it's over my head. Sorry.